# Payara 5 NP-Exception during deployment: TyrusServletContainerInitializer

Tags: exception, deployment, payara

With the payara 5.181 full release, deployment fails quite often with the following stack trace. This happens both in Netbeans-environment and with docker container.

After several retries, containing server-restarts, project clean-build, with and without osgi-cache cleanup (full rebuild in docker), but without changing anything in the application or server itself, eventually it will work again. Yet I am not able to reproduce this in a break down predictibile way.

For me, that doesn't seem to be a configuration issue. However, I also couldn't find a filed related payara bug. Does anyone knows a solution to this?

Failing deployment:

```
INFORMATION:   Clustered CDI Event bus initialized
INFORMATION:   Using OmniFaces version 3.0
INFORMATION:   Initializing Soteria 1.1-b01 for context ''
INFORMATION:   Registering WebSocket filter for url pattern /*
SCHWERWIEGEND:   Error invoking ServletContainerInitializer org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletContainerInitializer
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(TyrusServletContainerInitializer.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:5825)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.callServletContainerInitializers(WebModule.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:609)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:684)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2099)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1745)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:123)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:294)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:357)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.initialize(ApplicationLifecycle.java:538)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:514)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:549)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:545)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:544)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:567)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1475)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1857)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:564)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:251)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:190)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:516)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:213)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

SCHWERWIEGEND:   Startup of context  failed due to previous errors
SCHWERWIEGEND:   Exception during cleanup after start failed
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Manager has not yet been started
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:868)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:5927)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.stop(WebModule.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5743)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:609)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:684)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2099)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1745)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:123)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:294)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:357)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.initialize(ApplicationLifecycle.java:538)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:514)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:549)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:545)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:544)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:567)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1475)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1857)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:564)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:251)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:190)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:516)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:213)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

SCHWERWIEGEND:   ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:609)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:684)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2099)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1745)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:123)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:294)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:357)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.initialize(ApplicationLifecycle.java:538)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:514)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:549)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:545)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:544)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:567)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1475)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1857)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:564)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:251)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:190)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:516)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:213)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:5833)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.callServletContainerInitializers(WebModule.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5722)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(TyrusServletContainerInitializer.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:5825)
    ... 50 more

WARNUNG:   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:960)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:684)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2099)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1745)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:123)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:294)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:357)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.initialize(ApplicationLifecycle.java:538)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:514)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:549)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:545)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:544)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:567)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1475)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1857)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:564)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:251)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:190)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:516)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:213)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

SCHWERWIEGEND:   Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:123)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:294)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:357)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.initialize(ApplicationLifecycle.java:538)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:514)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:549)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:545)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:544)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:567)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1475)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1857)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:564)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:251)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:190)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:516)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:213)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

SCHWERWIEGEND:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:123)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:294)

    ...REMOVED PART OF THE LOG DUE TO CHARACTER SIZE LIMITATION...

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

SCHWERWIEGEND:   Exception while loading the app
SCHWERWIEGEND:   Undeployment failed for context 
SCHWERWIEGEND:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Working after some retries, exactly the same application and server (extract):

```
INFORMATION:   Running Payara Version: Payara Server  5.181 #badassfish (build 213)
...
INFORMATION:   Clustered CDI Event bus initialized
INFORMATION:   Registering WebSocket filter for url pattern /*
INFORMATION:   Using OmniFaces version 3.0
INFORMATION:   Initializing Soteria 1.1-b01 for context ''
INFORMATION:   Mojarra 2.4.0-m01.payara-p5 für Kontext '' wird initialisiert.
INFORMATION:   This application is running on BootsFaces1.2.0-
INFORMATION:   Running on PrimeFaces 6.2
INFORMATION:   Loading application [Staar] at [/]
```

**Update**

I might have found a somehow related bug at https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/21508, considering the websocket relation and the weird "50% chances" to be able to run it. The mentioned workaround didn't work for me.

The problem is gone when not making use of the JSF 2.3 f:websocket component and commenting out the according settings *javax.faces.ENABLE_CDI_RESOLVER_CHAIN* and *javax.faces.ENABLE_WEBSOCKET_ENDPOINT* in the web.xml.
As soon as I find time a will try to provide a minimal example.

Comment: Very curious, what made you think you needed to add "javax.faces.ENABLE_CDI_RESOLVER_CHAIN"?

Comment: When I remember right, this is inspired from your own blog (http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/p/jsf-23.html). Although stated explicitly for glassfish, I also used it for the derived payara when first playing around with websockets. It was active when experiencing the behaviour described above, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for letting me know where you got it from :) The setting was one we used during the development of 2.3, but got removed towards the end so it now does exactly nothing. I'll remove it from the blog there. Thanks again!

Comment: FWIW https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/5640

Answer (score 2):

I'm not fully sure how to solve this, but the problem is directly caused by there already being a filter in the application called "WebSocket filter".

This may be caused by the initialiser running twice, which indeed seems to happen as *"Registering WebSocket filter for url pattern /*"* is already printed before the exception. Printing that would be indicative of the first registration being done, so the second one fails.

You may want to check if there isn't a Tyrus implementation present in the war file. There shouldn't be one, as it's provided by Payara.

Comment: I've added some more information. There is no other Tyrus implementation in the war file.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same issue. This seems to be a payara bug, but there is an easy workaround by using OmniFaces. All you have to do (apart from including OmniFaces in your project) is change your web.xml from:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.ENABLE_WEBSOCKET_ENDPOINT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

to

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.SOCKET_ENDPOINT_ENABLED</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Then change your jsf tags from

```html
<f:websocket channel="XYZ" ... />
```

to

```html
<o:socket channel="XYZ" ... />
```

and lastly change the import of `@Push` and `@PushContext` from

```java
import javax.faces.push.Push;
import javax.faces.push.PushContext;
```

to

```java
import org.omnifaces.cdi.Push;
import org.omnifaces.cdi.PushContext;
```

So instead of using Tyrus (as provided by Payara) you can simply use the functionality provided by OmniFaces. That's because the JSR 356 implementation is largely based on the OmniFaces one. Hope this helps!